# How to force an update in a Vaadin Grid after a valueChange through the Grid Editor?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I would like to update a in the line being edited in the Grid Editor as soon as another value is altered. So for example if I change the currency in a purchase I want the amount to be adjusted for that currency. With that in mind I have:

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.getEditor().setEnabled(true);

grid.addColumn(Purchase::getAmount())
    .setEditorBinding(amountField, Purchase::setAmount);
grid.addColumn(Purchase::getCurrency())
    .setEditorBinding(currencyField, Purchase::setCurrency);

grid.getEditor().getBinder().addValueChangeListener(event ->
{
    Component component = event.getComponent();
    if(component.equals(currencyField))
    {
        Purchase purchase = binder.getBean();
        purchase.setAmount(amountAdjustedForCurrency(purchase.getCurrency()));
        // How do I update to the amount in the grid for that row?
    }
});
```

My question is how do I update the amount in the Grid? Even though the bean has been adjusted the screen isn't updated...

Answer (score 0):

First thing that occurs into my mind is to do programmatic forced close - reopen with edit in that value change listener.

grid.getEditor().save(); grid.getEditor().editRow(rowIndex);